# M2: Issue during install module via composer

Tags: magento2, composer

When I try install module via composer then I get issue from other extension which is already installed.

```
[user@s1 public_html]$ composer71 require new/modulemarketing


  [RuntimeException]
  Could not load package module/extensionname in https://repo.magento.com: [
  UnexpectedValueException] Could not parse version constraint 5.5.33 as ^5.2
  : Invalid version string "^5.2"



  [UnexpectedValueException]
  Could not parse version constraint 5.5.33 as ^5.2: Invalid version string "
  ^5.2"


require [--dev] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--fixed] [--no-progress] [--no-suggest] [--no-update] [--no-scripts] [--update-no-dev] [--update-with-dependencies] [--update-with-all-dependencies] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [--sort-packages] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--] [<packages>]...
```

Anyone have solution?

Comment: first `composer update`  after check

Answer (score 0):

Try to add your new/modulemarketing to your composer.json file and run the following command:

```
composer71 update new/modulemarketing
```

I hope that it helps.